# Mapping many-to-many without a join table in Hibernate/NHibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, orm, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have two tables:

```
CalendarEntry
  Id
  Date
  ...

Holiday
  Id
  Date
  ...
```

In my `CalendarEntry` class, I have a property like this

```
public ISet<Holiday> Holidays { ... }
```

which I want to associate to the `Holiday` instances that occur on the same `Date` as the `CalendarEntry`. However, I can't come up with how to do this.

I've tried mapping it as one-to-many, but one-to-many automatically assumes that it should perform the join using `CalendarEntry`'s `Id` column (presumably since it's the only property that is guaranteed to be unique, which it must be to be one-to-many).

I've tried mapping it as many-to-many, but it seems that many-to-many requires a separate join table, which I don't want in this case.

My question is: is it possible to map this in NHibernate, and how should I do it? If it's not possible, why?

Comment: Can you post the mapping you are trying to use?

Comment: I'm using NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes, so I don't have a HBM file, but I'll try posting the mappings I've used tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to do is set up a query to get the Holiday entries. I'm not sure this can be done using a mapping.

---

Additional info from my original answer, which may not apply: You can have the many-to-many relationship in NHibernate without creating a separate entity class for the join table entries, but the underlying data still needs to exist somewhere in the database.

Comment: My reluctancy to use a join table comes partly from resisting to modify the database schema, but mostly from the fact that the information already is there - the date columns in CalendarEntry and Holiday *is* the association between the entities, and a new join table seems redundant.

Comment: Yeah... it's a very loose coupling, though, where Hibernate expects it to be strong (using IDs). I'd set this up as a query for now.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using a property-ref, which I believe is available in NHibernate 2.1. I found it in the [link text](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-key) and here's the [jira](http://nhjira.koah.net/browse/NH-1272) for adding it to NHibernate.

I'm not sure this would work on a date column and you're definitely out of luck if your date field contains time data.

You can always leave the relationship out of the model and access the collection through a repository method, i.e. GetHolidaysForDate. This would make more sense to me since holidays are distinct from calendar entries and culture specific. Unless you're using the non-US meaning equivalent to "vacation."

Answer (score 0):

You could create a database view (or derived table query) containing the appropriate ids from `CalendarEntry` and `Holiday`, then map a many-to-many relationship using the view - this technically avoids having a join table, while allowing NHibernate to work the way it wants to.

You'll want to make sure NHibernate doesn't attempt to update the collections (probably some combination of `inverse="true"`and `cascade="none"`) and avoid modifying the them in code - I presume you're okay with this given you don't want a table at all.

Comment: This requires the database to join CalendarEntry and Holiday twice, once for the view, and once for fetching the actual data. Moreover, it gives the query optimizer additional leeway to trip over its feet: When trying this with oracle to join two rows, the nested loop join used when mapping with property-refs was replaced with a join to the view, which was computed using a hash join and a full table scan ...

Comment: You could use a materialised/indexed view if you're particularly worried about read performance, however given the problem domain there is likely to be a maximum of few thousand rows in these tables.
If property-ref is a viable solution, it's probably the best choice, but I've struggled with it before and this is a good workaround.